# Correct routing for nested resources

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

There is 'Type' model and 'Place' model. 'Place' describes places of entertainment: cafes, clubs, etc. Cafes, clubs, etc are 'Type'. I need to create routing to take all places by type:

```
resources :types do
  resources :places
end
```

It's good, now I can take places in `'index'` action of `PlacesController` with `params[:type_id]` (for example, `'/types/1/places'`). But I also need to get list of ALL places independently of their types. I can't do it using `'index'` action of `PlacesController`. How should I do this task according to Rails/REST philosophy? What's the best solution?

Answer (score 0):

You could do this:

```
resources :types do
  resources :places
end

resources :places
```

Comment: I mean that I have the same action 'index' for 2 different routes: in first case I should render all places, in the second case - all places with passed type_id - how can I do it?